# Buildozer failed to execute the last command

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

while I was trying to build,push and automatically run the apk on my device using `buildozer android debug deploy run` it shows these errors:

```
# Check configuration tokens 

# Ensure build layout

# Check configuration tokens

# Preparing build


# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/sahil/.buildozer/android/platform/apacheant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/sahil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/sahil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Distribution already compiled, pass.
# Build the application #21
# Package the application
 # Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 build.py --name demo --version 1.2.0 --package org.test.myapp --private /home/sahil/kivy/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I checked it out in documentation and also on internet but did not find anything about it.
AND I am just making a simple Hello World application:

```
#version.regex
#__version__= '1.0'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")


if __name__=="__main__":
    SimpleApp().run()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First raise the `log level = 2` in `buildozer.spec`,then it will show all logs and error clearly. Here in `.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/python 2.7 build.py` was missing. To fix this issue run this command `buildozer android clean` and then rebuild it using `buildozer android debug` or automatically run using `buildozer android debug deploy run`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are running an updated version of cython, all major release start form 0.21 and up, you have to downgrade cython to 0.20 ( sudo pip install cython==0.20 ) then removing .buildozer folder ( rm -Rf .buildozer ) and then rebuilding with 'buildozer android debug'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for may English
but would that help if in **Folder** that **App** is made
***(example: `your_user@your_user-virtualbox:~/Your_Desktop/(App_Folder_Name)$`
)*** with **pygame** or **kivy** module in **Linux OS** you would have 1 **main.py file** and **buildozer.spec** constructed with command ***buidozer init*** (`your_user@your_user-virtualbox:~/Your_Desktop/(Your_App_Folder_Name)$buildozer init`). For the fisrt time that you only should change is in (

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,pygame,jnius,sdl2,sdl2_image,sdl2_mixer,sdl2_ttf,png,jpeg
```

) you need add requirements, save the file and close it.
Than in Your_App_folder with main.py and buildozer.spec ***you need download every module that you use trought import in main.py using terminal *pip3 install pygame**** (example:

```
your_user@your_user-virtualbox:~/Your_Desktop/(Your_App_Folder_Name)$pip3 install pygame
```

) and etc. even if the error by download occure better to do that and then install next module but ***you need a Internet connection even to build App with buildozer*** and for the first time lets say to wait 30 minutes or more that everything is executed and you get at the end in terminal something similar like:

```
# Android packaging done!
# APK myapp-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk available in the bin directory                                                                            
your_user@your_user-virtualbox:~/Desktop/a$
```

if that would not work than you have other problems maybe update, upgrade or reinstall everything and install new. You can use Ubuntu, Lubuntu, etc. and maybe use VirtualBox too.

***Do Not Forget to have Internet Connection and install with Terminal every Module in Your_App_folder with pip.***