# Creating APK from Kivy on Mac OS X fails after compile

Tags: android, python, macos, kivy, buildozer

My background is in HTML/JS, so compiling is new for me. While attempting to build my python project in Kivy to an Android .apk, I am getting an error I do not understand:

```
Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy"
```

Here is a portion of the tail end of the debug output...

```
Compiling /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: [libinstall] Error 1 (ignored)
PYTHONPATH=/Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: \
        /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -t /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/compileall.py \
        -d /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages -f \
        -x badsyntax /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Listing /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages ...
PYTHONPATH=/Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: \
        /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -t -O /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/compileall.py \
        -d /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages -f \
        -x badsyntax /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Listing /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages ...
PYTHONPATH=/Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: \
        /Users/Travis/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -t -c "import lib2to3.pygram, lib2to3.patcomp;lib2to3.patcomp.PatternCompiler()"
Leaving ARM environment
cp: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_ctypes*.so: No such file or directory
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Here is the full debug, for those who want it...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/45lgdhk5y4uj8eg/KivyDebug.txt?dl=1

Also, my buildozer.spec file...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5p43jjts49rzza/buildozer.spec?dl=1

EDIT: Downgrading Cython per the advice [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140927/4096787) did not help.
EDIT2: Tried changing requirements to kivy==master. No luck.
EDIT3: Tried chmod -R 777 on both source and buildozer folders. No luck.

Comment: Might be better to just provide the buildozer.spec and debug here, as links can go dead in the future.

Comment: Thanks. However, It s **HUGE** log, and I question whether 1.6Mb of raw text on a single page would not be a serious TL:DR; for all but a select few. I've had this dropbox account for a long time though, and I seldom if ever move things from it - I just add space. It seemed like the best option.

Comment: OK, I added SOME of the debug.

Comment: If I were you , I would bring this to the kivy users support google group(just google it). There are some very knowledgeable kivy folks there

Answer (score 1):

OK, I came across the answer to my own problem a while ago and I'm posting it here in case someone else makes the same boneheaded mistake. Basically, I did not read the instructions carefully enough in [the documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html). The instructions clearly state "**navigate to your project directory** and run: buildozer init". I did not navigate to the project folder. I was building in my user directory, hence "/Users/Travis/". Hence the "No such file or directory" error.

You may be asking "How do you expect buildozer to know where your project is?"

Well, the next step says to configure "buildozer.spec", and in there, there is a place to put your path to the main.py, which by default is ".", so I changed that. It actually worked up to the point that it has to write any files.

So, if you're having the same issue as me, you might just need to read more carefully.

Comment: did you got this error `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'PKG-INFO'` after run `buildozer android debug deploy run`??