# Buildozer error while trying to compile a Kivy app

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I use Buildozer on colab.research.google.com. When I try to compile a simple *.py file containing a Kivy code, I get the errors explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072588/buildozer-failed-to-execute-the-last-command).
I tried the methods suggested in the answers, but they don't work at all.
In the `main.py` file there are no bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add those in `requirements`:

```
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0
```

And what are those other plugins are you using?

Comment: Just Kivy. I'll try to add the code you suggested.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, got the same issue.